# Ant property glob into global property space

Tags: ant, build, properties

I'd like to do something like a property set globbing from a set of properties, to a new one, but not save the result in a propertyset, but rather in the global property space.

For example:

```
<syspropertyset>
    <propertyref prefix="foo."/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="foo.*" to="bar.*"/>
</syspropertyset>
```

Will map all the properties like foo.something to bar.something, but they won't be generally available to other tasks, they are instead limited in scope to the propertyset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `echoproperties` task and go via a property file.  Something like:

```
<property name="foo.bar" value="bahh" />
<property name="foo.baz" value="bazz" />

<propertyset id="fooz">
    <propertyref prefix="foo."/>
    <mapper type="glob" from="foo.*" to="bar.*"/>
</propertyset>

<echoproperties destfile="bar.properties">
    <propertyset refid="fooz" />
</echoproperties>
<property file="bar.properties"/>

<echoproperties prefix="foo"/>
<echoproperties prefix="bar"/>
```

Result (some verbiage removed to simplify):

```
[echoproperties] foo.bar=bahh
[echoproperties] foo.baz=bazz
[echoproperties] bar.bar=bahh
[echoproperties] bar.baz=bazz
```